# How to get a result without using [0]

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running this query

```
$results = DB::connection('selection')
                                    ->select("
                                            SELECT id, name, email
                                            FROM users
                                            WHERE email = $this->email
                                   ");
```

I expect to only get on result from this, which I do get, this is my output

```
array:1 [
  0 => {
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "Ted Wood"
    +"email": "tedwood@email.com"
  }
]
```

What I would like to know is how can I access `name` without having to do `$results[0]->name` I would like to do `$results->name`.

Since it's only 1 item I'm getting I don't see a need for a foreach loop

Comment: Maybe `->first()`?

Comment: @u_mulder - I get this error ` Call to a member function first() on array`

Comment: Then just `select('....')[0]` but not sure what can happen when array is empty.

Comment: better you should use like `$results = DB::connection('selection')->table('users')->where('email',$this->email)->select("id", "name", "email")->first;`

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select()` returns an array. The `first()` method works with collections, so you need to wrap the array in the collection to use the `first()` method.

```
$results = collect($results)->first()
```

Comment: I don't want to use eloquent as I'm connecting to a different database rather then the main one

Comment: @Nix I changed the comment. check please

Answer (score 0):

using [first](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-first)

```
$results =collect(DB::connection('selection')
                                    ->select("
                                            SELECT id, name, email
                                            FROM users
                                            WHERE email = $this->email
                                   "))->first();
```

but i think the best way to do it would be like:

```
  $results = DB::connection('selection')->table('users')->select('id', 'name', 'email')
        ->where('email',$this->email)->limit(1)->first();
```

Comment: I get this error ` Call to a member function first() on array`

Comment: first comes after getting data from db, mean the data comes to you then you get first, while 'limit' means that data will not come from db in the first place, witch gave you more speed

Comment: and if you used limit only (with get()) you will end up with array with one element

Answer (score 0):

Use reset pointer like this

```
reset($results)->name
```